# Audio file without header

Tags: audio, codec

I got audio file without header so I'm not sure what format it is. I think that is mpeg4 celp or amr-wb. I need a codecs and application which is not basing on file header and let me choose codec to play audio. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try dragging it on a player that supports a lot type of audio file format. what do you mean by header? is it same as extension?

Comment: By a header i mean few first hexadecimal values in file. For example in *.amr files it is:  #!AMR.$ (Hex: 23 21 41 4D 52 0A 24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very difficult to make a guess at the format without a header. This is especially true of compressed formats, as you can't simply assume a PCM coding type and then plot the waveform as a sanity check. My suggestion would be to manually prefix the data with an assumed header, store the resulting file, then try to play it back and see if it sounds like garbage or not.

If you have some other *a priori* information about the signal, such as if it is mono or stereo, endianess, data rate, etc., you can cut down on the dimensions of your trial and error approach.